# Cannot set ILMerge path to console

Tags: windows, path, console

I install ILMerge.exe; path is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe.`

I want to set the command to the Path so I can type ilmerge anywhere to use the application.
I googled and tried all the following but none works:

```
setx -m ilmerge;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe
setx -M ilmerge;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe
setx -m %PATH%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe
setx /S system /U administrator ilmerge;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe
```

I then tried to add, the GUI's Environment Variables, click New and input the **variable** "ilmerge" and **value** "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe". But in command prompt and type in ilmerge, still gives me

> 'ilmerge' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or bath file.

Why something as basic as setting a path that confusing..

Answer (score 0):

`PATH` environment variable must contains path to **folders**, not files!

for example

```
setx PATH "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ILMerge;%PATH%"
```

Answer (score 0):

For using ILmerge in command line instead of

```
ilmerge /out:Merged.dll Primary.dll Secondary1.dll Secondary2.dll
```

you can use

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" /out:Merged.dll Primary.dll Secondary1.dll Secondary2.dll
```

By This way you can use ILmerge without having to to change PATH environment variable